# Expressions soutenues pour répondre à une inquiétude

Tags: expressions

**Contexte**: Je viens de découvrir qu'en français, on distingue au moins deux registres: *soutenu* et *familier*. Mon but est d'améliorer mes connaissances sur le côté soutenu pour communiquer efficacement dans les courriels, le travail, etc.

J'ai reçu un e-mail de la part de mon professeur français me disant:

> J’espère que vous allez bien ..... porte-toi bien.

Comment répondre **de manière soutenue** à ce genre d'e-mail ? Pouvez-vous s'il vous plaît me donner quelques exemples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avant tout, ce type de formule à la fin des mails est typique de la période de confinement du COVID-19 et remplace le classique *Cordialement*.

Il y a plusieurs façons de répondre formellement en fonction du lien que vous avez avec l'interlocuteur. Voici quelques exemples :

> Je vais bien et j'espère qu'il en est de même pour vous.
>
> Nous allons bien et j'espère qu'il en est de même pour vous et votre famille.
>
> J'espère aussi que tout va bien de votre côté. Portez-vous bien.
>
> J'espère aussi que tout va bien de votre côté. Prenez soin de vous et de votre famille.

Vous pouvez aussi saisir l'opportunité de justifier ou d'expliquer une situation particulière :

> Je suis touché que vous preniez de mes nouvelles. Malheureusement, ma
>   mère est souffrante depuis quelques jours et je risque d'avoir un peu
>   de retard dans la remise du rapport. En comptant sur votre
>   compréhension.